# Kinect re-position

Tags: navigation, mapping, kinect, turtlebot, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to re-position the kinect on turtlebot to the top of it, instead of the default position. Will i get a proper map now ?  or should I change some robot-model-parameters to achieve that? If so what all parameters and where?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30985/kinect-re-position/) by [prasanna](https://answers.ros.org/users/1968/prasanna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2012-04-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Default mapping by the gmapping uses the fake laser from the kinect. So the obtacles that are in the plane of the kinect's height will be detected. So if your environment has the obstacles of that height, then mapping should be fine even if you change the height. You can visualize the same in rviz. If you want to change the model of the robot in rviz then you may have to change the URDF of the robot. Please refer to the launch files and locate the model and try to edit it and see if the model is changed in rviz.

Hope it helps,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used to put `Kinect` on top of `Turtlebot` and `gmapping` was as good as default config without really modifying mapping parameters. Adding to @karthik's thorough answer, one thing to note is to save enough space in front of `Kinect` (as default setting does) so as not to violate its minimum distance requirement toward objects.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2012-04-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1